# Variable not defined, strange scope of variable

Tags: javascript, variables, scope

I am getting the following error...in running the javascript below in a .js file.

> Uncaught ReferenceError: startloc is not defined

But I thought if I declare the variable at the top of the script it is visible to all the methods below them.. I don't know why it says it is not defined...

```
var startLoc = new Array();
var endLoc = new Array();


//Map Initialisation
function initMap() {
}

//Marker addon
function addMarker(lattitude, longitude) {
}

// Sets the map on all markers in the array.
function setMapOnAll(map) {
}

//Clear markers on the map
function clearMarkers() {
}

//delete markers array 
function deleteMarkers() {
}

//Plot the markers on the map  
$("document").ready(function(){
    $("#getData").submit(function(event){
        event.preventDefault();
        var reset = 0;
        window.setInterval(function(){
            $.ajax({
                url : "/getVehiclePosition.php",
                type: "POST",
                datatype: "json",
                data: "",
                success: function(data, textStatus, jqXHR)
                {                    
                    var json_obj = $.parseJSON(data);//parse JSON
                    deleteMarkers();

                    for (var i in json_obj) 
                    {
                       if (reset = 0){
                            startloc[i-1] = "X";
                            reset = 1;
                        } else {
                            endLoc[i-1] = "Y";
                            reset = 0;
                        }   

                        console.log(startloc[i-1]);
                        console.log(endloc[i-1]);

                    }

                },
                error: function (jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown)
                {
                    console.error(
                        "The following error occurred: "+
                        textStatus, errorThrown
                    );
                }
            });

        }, 15000);
    });
});
```

Comment: JavaScript identifiers are case sensitive

Answer (score 1, accepted):

typo - you are declaring it with the capital "L"

```
var startLoc = new Array();
```

but using it with a lower case "l"

```
startloc[i-1] = "X";
```

should be

```
 startLoc[i-1] = "X";
```

same with your console.log for endLoc:

```
console.log(endloc[i-1]);
```

also - your document ready is incorrect as well - you dont need the quotes in there - change it to:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
```

Comment: wow! how did I not see that, thank you so much! works like a charm. :-)

Answer (score 0):

typo `startLoc` to `startloc`. Try corrcting

Comment: ha ha.. You won.. I loose